# How do I make an updatepanel delay form submittion until it is complete?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have an update panel surrounding a grid with a bunch of inputs and calculations done serverside to update the footer for the grid. All of the grid inputs are set to trigger the updatepanel on change. This grid is part of a larger form.

When I am in an input in the grid and change a value, but click submit on the form, the update panel is triggered, but the form submit is triggered as well (with the old value for the input if the update panel doesn't finish refreshing in time). How do I delay the form submit until after the update panel finishes?